# Take sentence from user input with C

Tags: arrays, c, input

I wana take input from user and then print, I think I should also allocate memory could someone show me how to do that properly?

Here is my try:

```
    int days = 1;
    char * obligation[1500];
    char * dodatno[1500];

    puts("Enter nuber of days till obligation:\n");
    scanf(" %d", &days);
    puts("Enter obligation:\n");
    scanf(" %s", obligation);
    puts("Sati:\n");
    scanf(" %s", dodatno);

printf("%s|%s|%s \n",days,obligation,dodatno);
```

Comment: Can use `%ms` if you use `glibc`. [scanf Example](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: change `char * obligation[1500];` to `char  obligation[1500];` would be OK.  If the variable needs very large memory room ,then to malloc it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to allocate dynamically. Just store it in a char array.
And `printf("%s|%s|%s....` is wrong in your case, change the first `%s` to `%d`

Here is an example of how that would look like

```
int main()
{
    int days = 1;
    char obligation[256];
    char dodatno[256];

    printf("Enter number of days till obligation: ");
    scanf("%d", &days);
    printf("Enter obligation: ");
    scanf("%s", obligation);
    printf("Sati: ");
    scanf("%s", dodatno);

    printf("%d | %s | %s", days, obligation, dodatno);

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to read in the whole line, you could use fgets and parse using strtok:

```
char* days;
char* obligation;
char* dodatno;
char line[256];

printf("Enter days, obligation and sati: ");
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

days = strtok(line, " ");
obligation = strtok(NULL, " ");
dodatno = strtok(NULL, "\n");

printf("%s | %s | %s", days, obligation, dodatno);

return 0;
```

Comment: I have problem when I type just one word it works fine but if I type sentence it skips all next scans... Any idea why is this?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic scanf reads what you give it, `%s` reads a word. You can use `fgets()` to read the line, and then parse text into `obligation` and `dodatno`

Comment: @VladimirDjukic added code in my answer to read in a whole line